# match json data to class properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have used one webapi method where [FromBody] i used my class object.
like below:

```html
 public HttpResponseMessage ProcessResource([FromBody]FileContent contentvalue)
    {//some business logic
    }
```

and below is my json format which i am sending from client machine:

```html
 {"FileContent":{"ResourceStrings":[{"StringKey":"TestKey","StringID":1,"Value":"TestKey"},{"StringKey":"SampleKey","StringID":2,"Value":"Test key 1"},{"StringKey":"HomeKey","StringID":3,"Value":"Home DEV"},{"StringKey":"custom.WVF.ContactForm.Name","StringID":4,"Value":"NAME"},{"StringKey":"custom.CMS.MenuItem","StringID":5,"Value":"CMS.MenuItem"}]},}
```

below is FileContent class used:

```html
public class ResourceString
{
    public string StringKey { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the StringKey
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// StringKey
    /// </value>
    public int StringID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the StringID
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// StringID
    /// </value>
    public string Value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Value
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Value
    /// </value>
}
/// <summary>
/// Added RootObject new class to serialize and deserialize for resource string
/// </summary>
public class RootObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the list of ResourceString
    /// </summary>
    public List<ResourceString> ResourceStrings { get; set; }
}
public class FileContent
{
    public List<ResourceString> ResourceStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i am sending json data from client machine and debugging my web api method then FileContent object value is null.

How do i get json data in this method parameter?

Now i am able to get json data in that method using Roma's solution.
After getting data i need again i need to deserialize it to ResourceString then again i should get my json format like below:

```html
 {"ResourceStrings":[{"StringKey":"TestKey","StringID":1,"Value":"TestKey"},{"StringKey":"SampleKey","StringID":2,"Value":"Test key 1"},{"StringKey":"HomeKey","StringID":3,"Value":"Home DEV"},{"StringKey":"custom.WVF.ContactForm.Name","StringID":4,"Value":"NAME"},{"StringKey":"custom.CMS.MenuItem","StringID":5,"Value":"CMS.MenuItem"}]}
```

How do i make it deserialize to get the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `RootObject`:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public FileContent FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

And change your action to:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ProcessResource([FromBody]RootObject obj)
{
    //some business logic
}
```

**OR**

If you want to parse into `FileContent` your `JSON` should be:

```
{"ResourceStrings":[{"StringKey":"TestKey","StringID":1,"Value":"TestKey"},{"StringKey":"SampleKey","StringID":2,"Value":"Test key 1"},{"StringKey":"HomeKey","StringID":3,"Value":"Home DEV"},{"StringKey":"custom.WVF.ContactForm.Name","StringID":4,"Value":"NAME"},{"StringKey":"custom.CMS.MenuItem","StringID":5,"Value":"CMS.MenuItem"}]}
```

Comment: Hi Roma, Thanks for your quick reply. Your solution worked fine. one small issue i am facing. I am updating my question above. Please reply me for that also.

Comment: @Vikash, I saw your edit, could you explain little more about your problem?

Comment: Hi Roma, Any how i managed later issue but your solution worked for me. I am upvoting your answer. Thank you.